# Do I need to maintain the HTTPS (SSL) state after user logged even the data are not sensitive?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https

I have a website where users can post ads and view them. I am using ASP.net build it. So normally site is free for to view ads. But if anybody wants to post an ad he or she needs to be a registered user. So if an user try to Post an ad without logging then he will be redirect to login page. So I want to enable SSL for login page to securely transfer information over the internet.

Here few things you should know.

I just only need to secure the user name and passwords.
Ads post by users are not sensitive data. So it is OK if it transfer through non secure path.

I dont want to enable SSL for every page. Because it will slow down page loading and it is a CPU intense task.

So how to achieve this? Do I need to maintain the HTTPS state after user logged under SSL connection until he post articles and until he log out?

Cant I just secure the login page for authenticate the user and then go with normal pages? Keep in mind that I need to keep the logged information because I saw in an another blog that saying When you go from HTTPS to HTTP all the states are being lost. Is that true?

So Help me here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Worrying about SSL slowing down your website sounds like it's way too early to worry about at this point. Don't prematurely optimize things. Wait until you try it before you decide it's going to make things too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain SSL for every page once a user is logged in so that you can use secure cookies for the authentication cookie. This can be set using the `requireSSL="true"` in the `web.config` ([MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). You definitely should use secure cookies for authentication, and you'll only be able to utilize that cookie over HTTPS.

Or as Scott Hanselman put it in [this seriously old blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToForceAllCookiesToSecureUnderASPNET11.aspx):

> In order to prevent Session Hijacking, when you've got a secure site,
>   it's a good idea to mark your cookies as "secure," meaning that they
>   can't be accessed over HTTP. This prevents folks from being issued
>   cookies over HTTPS then switching to HTTP in order to access the
>   cookie with sniffers or other evil.

This question has also been covered at [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/can-a-session-be-hijacked-if-the-user-is-redirected-from-https-to-http-after-log) and [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203409/do-logged-in-users-need-to-browse-a-site-over-https).

More Reading: [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 9: Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-9.html)